# text to XML with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, text, saxon

I have a system that creates a simple text file with the same structure. Originally it is a HTML-file that I run through Lynx to get a text file. This text I want to convert to XML to be able to pick up a URL in the text file. The system I'm working with can pick up that from XML.

The text file looks like this:

```
References

   1. url one
   2. url two
   3. url three
   4. url four
```

I'm a newbie here and I can't post four links in a post yet.

I have a XSL that when run through Saxon gives me an error from the text file that Content is not allowed in prolog and it then refers to "References"
It is not shown here but first line is a return, second line is "References" and third line is a return again.

Here is the XSL I'm using.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
  <xsl:variable name="base-uri" select="base-uri(.)"/>
<xsl:variable name="document-uri" select="document-uri(.)"/>
<xsl:variable name="filename" select="(tokenize($document-uri,'/'))[last()]"/>  
<xsl:variable name="src">
 <doc>
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text($filename, 'iso-8859-1'), '\r\n')">
    <line><xsl:value-of select="."/></line>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </doc>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">         
 <xsl:result-document href = "src1.xml">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$src"/>
 </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks

Jan

Comment: How do you call Saxon exactly, are you passing in an input document? What kind of document is that? If you want to process plain text then don't pass in input document, instead name your template `<xsl:template name="main"><xsl:copy-of select="$src1"/></xsl:template>` and call Saxon with `-it:main -o:src1.xml -xsl:sheet.xsl`.

Comment: You will also have to change `<xsl:variable name="filename" select="(tokenize($document-uri,'/'))[last()]"/> ` to `<xsl:param name="filename"/>` and pass that parameter of the file name in to Saxon (or hard code it (`<xsl:param name="filename" select="'myfile.txt'"/>`)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found another way in my system to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The message "Content is not allowed in prolog" means that you've given a file as input to an XML parser which it doesn't recognize as XML. In this case that's presumably your text file, which I suspect you supplied as the primary input to the transformation.

When your main input is a text file, the usual approach is to start processing at a named template, for example

```
<xsl:param name="inputFile"/>
<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:variable name="inputFileContent" select="unparsed-text($inputFile)"/>
  ...
```

and then invoke the transformation without a source document, using `-it:main` if running from the command line.